# LaTeX table created same as following table

Tags: tables

How I can insert this table in LaTeX?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) What have you done till now? Which is your specific problem? Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). There are many posts concerning tables, have you searched?

Comment: Is the problem the spanning cells?  If so you might like to read this:  https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#Spanning

Comment: The table shown in the screenshot is a singularly unappealing. Why would you you want to replicate its look? Incidentally, is one of the requirements that all nine columns be equally wide?

Comment: The better you ask, the more you get help. Ask as specific as possible.

Comment: thank you. I was having question about column assigning and the gap defining between two columns.

Comment: I did this part but it is not coming right way

Comment: \begin{table}
  \centering
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \begin{tabular}{|p{4cm}|c|c|c|c|}
 \hline
\multirow{2}{2cm}{\textbf{Sequence}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Hall Sensor Input}} &  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Active MOSFETs}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Phase Current}}\\
    % \hline
    % \textbf{Inactive Modes} & \textbf{Description}\\
    \cline{2-5}
    & \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C} & \textbf{}

Comment: @d.r Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: this is bibtex file where I have included bibliography and I have called that in bibliography section

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I had a bit to fight with this, I removed all vertical lines, and introduced new columns. I had to manually space the existing ones, in order to make them fit (due to `multirow` and `multicolumn` together I think), but I got it working

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,array,multirow}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\bfseries}c}
\begin{document}

   \begin{table} \centering \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2} 
   \begin{tabular}{cc@{\qquad}cc@{\qquad}cc@{\qquad}*{3}{c}} 
   \toprule 
   \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Sequence\#}} & \multicolumn{3}{C}{Hall Sensor Input} & \multicolumn{2}{C}{\multirow{2}{*}{Active PWMs}} 
   & \multicolumn{3}{C}{Phase Current}\\ %
    &\textbf{A} & \textbf{B}&\textbf{C}& & &\textbf{A} & \textbf{B}&\textbf{C}\\
    \midrule
    1&0&0&1&PWM1(Q1)&PWM4(Q4)&DC+&Off&DC-\\
    2&0&0&0&PWM1(Q1)&PWM2(Q2)&DC+&DC-&Off\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]